# How to make specific columns into rows and change specific values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the title is very vague but I didn't know how to explain this question better, if you have any suggestions please do tell me.

I have this table:

CRAccountID DBAccountID Value

And I want to have a row for each CRAccountID and DBAccountID for example:

```
CRAccountID DBAccountID Value
100          111         10
```

I want to get these records:

```
AccountID  Value
100         10
111        -10
```

If you haven't noticed yet I also want to make the DBAccountID value in minus.

I tried it by selecting both of them and doing a `Union` but it takes way too much time when the table gets bigger (the table can contain more than 4 million records)

Here's my code:

```
select CRAccountID as AccountID, Value from MyTable
UNION
select DBAccountID as AccountID, -Value as Value from MyTable
```

Note: my code is much much bigger than this with almost 4 joins in each union therefore it becomes so slow.

I'm using Microsoft SQL.

Comment: If you want every row then a full table scan is required so not sure if there is a quicker option, but are you just selecting specific transactions?

Comment: By transactions are you referring to records in this table? If so, no. I'm trying to get a report of all the data (using paging or such)

Comment: One small thing, if you use UNION ALL instead of UNION it doesn't do the step where it tries to de-dupe the result set.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot that transaction is ambiguous in this context! I did mean every row, as each represents a debit/credit transaction. Good tip about union all, and I see you got a good answer - I didn't know about apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to unpivot the data.  I would recommend `apply`:

```
select v.account, v.value
from t cross apply
     (values (t.CRAccountID, t.value),
             (t.DBAccountID, - t.value)
     ) v(account, value) ;
```

You can express your complex as a CTE or subquery.  Or just include it in the query before the `cross apply`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed.